# Workaround for uncatchable NPE from WebViewDatabase on pre-Gingerbread devices

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm getting this uncatchable exception on pre-Gingerbread devices:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getCacheTotalSize(WebViewDatabase.java:735)
 at android.webkit.CacheManager.trimCacheIfNeeded(CacheManager.java:557)
 at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:195)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I only use WebView for AdMob ads, so this is quite annoying.

Is there a way to stop these crashes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (before loading any ads) if your minSdkLevel is Donut or later:

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT < 9) {
    try {
        Method m = WebViewDatabase.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCacheTotalSize");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(WebViewDatabase.getInstance(thisContext));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // disable webview/ads
    }
}
```

If your minSdkLevel is earlier than Donut, you need to use another way to test for the SDK level:

```
private static int getSdkInt() {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(VERSION.SDK);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this:

```
public static final boolean webViewIsProbablyCorrupt(Context context) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase cacheDb = context.openOrCreateDatabase("webviewCache.db", 0, null);

        if (cacheDb != null) {
            cacheDb.close();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.w(TAG, t);
    }

    return true;
}
```